# PyQt5 WebEngine does not display pages like angular.dev or react.dev properly

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I can't figure out how to make pages like react.dev, angular.dev, facebook.com, or chat.openai load properly.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

# Define a class MyWebBrowser that inherits from QMainWindow
class MyWebBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Call the constructor of the base class (QMainWindow)
        super(MyWebBrowser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create the main window and set its title
        self.window = QWidget()

        # Create a horizontal layout for the main window
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self.window)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Create a QWebEngineView widget for displaying web content
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        # Access the settings of the web engine
        self.settings = self.browser.settings()

        # Enable JavaScript in the web engine
        self.settings.setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)

        # Set the initial URL to "https://react.dev"
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://react.dev"))

        # Define a mobile user agent string
        self.mobile_user_agent = (
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        )

        # Set the user agent for the web page
        self.browser.page().profile().defaultProfile().setHttpUserAgent(self.mobile_user_agent)

        # Set the layout for the main window
        self.window.setLayout(self.layout)

        # Set the default size for the main window
        self.defaultSize = QSize(500, 800)
        self.window.setFixedSize(self.defaultSize)

        # Show the main window
        self.window.show()

# Create a QApplication instance
app = QApplication([])

# Create an instance of MyWebBrowser
window = MyWebBrowser()

# Start the application event loop
app.exec_()
```

I hope the mentioned pages load and function properly; for instance, the button to switch to the dark theme on React doesn't work, or the background of Angular doesn't display.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "load properly", since in your last paragraph you're mentioning a *button switch*, which is quite different from a *loading* issue. Also, provide proper environment information (such as OS and Qt - not PyQt - version). Finally, consider that Qt5 is now considered obsolete, and its QtWebEngine module uses a chromium engine that, for web standards, is potentially obsolete too.

Comment: My bad for not making myself clear. Some pages like React or Angular just don't load right. Take chat.openai.com, for instance – the login and register buttons are basically on vacation. Didn't realize it was ancient tech :,) Any other options you'd suggest I dive into?

Comment: If you want to show websites oriented on web-development, ignoring the browser version is an irresponsible mistake. A 2-3 year old browser is often obsolete, especially for such websites; if your program must access such sites, consider switching to Qt6. In case you *do* know specific requirements for a certain website you have to use in your program, check the minimum browser version requirement. For instance, the latest Qt5 (>=5.15.3) uses Chromium 87 (released on April 2021): the current one (Jan 5/2024) is 122. See [QtWebEngine/ChromiumVersions](//wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/ChromiumVersions).

Comment: It's still a little premature to consider Qt5 obsolete. The [commercial LTS version will be supported until 26-5-2025](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.15_Release#Qt_5.15_LTS_Commercial_Releases). Also, many Linux distros are still backporting patches for the open source edition, and that's unlikely to change much [until KDE 6 is out of beta](https://community.kde.org/Schedules/February_2024_MegaRelease) and widely deployed. Beyond that, there will still be a lot of legacy KDE/Qt apps around that will need continued Qt5 support.